# Animation Queue-Loop with jQuery/Promise

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-animate, fadein

I trying to figure out, how I can loop through an animation_queue and wait for the previous one to finish before the next one starts.

Currently is something like this (but really akward ..):

```
let animation_queue = [];
function button_state(form, state) { 
    animation_queue.push(state);

    var box = $(form).find('.btn_state_box');

    animation_queue.reduce(function(prev, curr, _){
        return prev.then(function() {
            animation_queue.shift();
            return box.find("[class*='btn__state__']").fadeOut(500, function(){
                return box.find("[class*='btn__state__" + curr + "']").fadeIn(500)
            }).promise()
        });
    }, $.when());
}
```

So the basic idea behind this is, I get different states from an ajax request and want to show it in a button with a nice animation. Sometimes I get a faster response, sometimes slowly, but it should always finish the animation before starting the next one.

Comment: Are you sure that your `box.find(...).fadeOut(500, function() {return box.find(...).fadeIn(500);}).promise()` expression returns the promise you are expecting?
I wonder if `box.find(...).fadeOut(500).promise().then(() => box.find(...).fadeIn(500).promise())` might stand a better chance?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I'll give it a try :) thanks mate

Comment: I think you will also need to raise an `inProgress` flag when a reduction is in progress; and lower it when the reduction is complete. Add to the queue unconditionally but only start a fresh reduction if the flag is down.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 this:

animation_queue.reduce(function(prev, curr, _){
        return prev.then(function() {
            return box.find("[class*='btn__state__']").fadeOut(500).promise().then(() => {
                animation_queue.shift();
                return box.find("[class*='btn__state__" + curr + "']").fadeIn(500)
            }).promise()
        });
    }, $.when());

Finally does what i want to do. Thanks!